# Riak KV: how to reinitialize data directories

Tags: database, riak, riak-kv

Is it possible to "recreate"/"reinitialize" all data directories for database riak? I don't need to keep data - just to start from 0. If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the backend you are using, you may just stop Riak (`riak stop`), delete the [data directory](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/backing-up/#os-specific-directory-locations) (usually under `/var/lib/riak/bitcask` or `/var/lib/riak/leveldb`) and start Riak (`riak start`). Riak should be able to start normally. If you are running a cluster, clean up all node of the cluster prior to starting them up, so that the data don't get re-populated from replicas.

Check out the [Backing Up](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/backing-up/) page, it will help you understand how Riak data directories work.

**Clarification:** The described procedure is for ***Riak KV*** and may not apply to other Riak products (e.g. Riak TS).

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark it as answered for other people.

Comment: If you change the `ring_size` (or other config maybe?), then you also have to wipe the `/var/lib/riak/ring` folder as well. Otherwise, after wiping leveldb and restarting riak, it still generated the old `ring_size` number of partition folders in leveldb. You can verify with `ls leveldb | wc -l`.

Comment: For RiakTS 1.5.2, this did not work - and what i mean by that  is after deleting the leveldb data, restarting the server just recreated the directories in leveldb, and my table was still there (I am trying to delete the table itself so i can recreate its definition - i.e. alter table)

Comment: @Nick This is for Riak KV. RiakTS is a different product and therefore may require a different procedure. Sorry I can't help you with RiakTS.

Comment: @vempo - It wasn't explicit, however I assumed it was for the KV.  While different products, they are similar, so I had a reasonable expectation for the behavior to be the same... I guess not.  Hoping my comment saves someone else some time.

Comment: @Nick - Well, back in June 2016 it was kind of explicit :) Also, there is a special tag for riak-ts but not for riak-kv. Probably because Riak KV had been called just "Riak" before Riak TS was released. Anyway, I think you have a point and will try to clarify this at least in the answer (as I don't have rights to edit posts).

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue with Riak TS 1.5.2.

I was able to clear all tables on my development host (MacOSX) by stopping RiakTS and then removing the top-level **data** directory.  When I restarted RiakTS, it recreated and reinitialized the **data** directory.

*This is not an ideal development flow.  I really hope Basho is able to add support for DROP TABLE construct.*